# Is it any open source Bitcoin exchange available

Tags: exchanges, open-source

Is it any open source Bitcoin exchange code is available

Answer (score 1):

Justcoin uses [snow](https://github.com/justcoin/snow) which is open sorce. I don't know if you are asking about Justcoin or Snow, either way, any of those two should be the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

openex is another open source exchange but the trade engine is not free and you should pay for that. Can be found on https://github.com/r3wt/openex